# use an if...else statement as a return value in sql

Tags: sql, if-statement

I'm trying to write his in sql:

```
SET `Field` = (
    If `Field` is empty then "b", 
    if `Field` is not empty, concat(`Field`,"_b"))
```

Meaning, if `Field` had value a it would change to a_b, if it was empty, it would change to b
Is there an sql synthax that creates this if..else statement properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF(Field = "" or Field IS NULL,'b',concat(Field,'_b'))
```

Comment: @n00bprogrammer, you can't use an if statement inside a query or command so either your peursdo code is is wrong or this isn't what you want

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I'm not sure I understand what you mean. It is possible my pseudocode isn't perfect. This answer worked great for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement.

Example:

```
SELECT 
    CASE  
        WHEN myField IS NULL THEN 'b'
        WHEN myField = '' THEN 'b'
        ELSE myField + '_b'
    END 
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) keyword.

Something like

```
UPDATE tbl
SET field = 
    CASE
        WHEN field = ''
            THEN 'b'
            ELSE field + '_b'
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cases but you can shorten it like this:

```
 set Field = isnull(field, '') 
             +  case when isnull(field, '') = '' then '' else '_' end 
             + 'b'
```